# How to find partial duplicate in array?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to remove partial duplicate value from an Array.

```
['John', 'Johnson', 'Mike', 'Tim', 'Timberland']
```

I want remove partial duplicate value.
in this case, I want keep longer string value.

```
['Johnson', 'Mike', 'Timberland']
```

Any good idea?

Comment: What happens if there are `foo`, `foobar`, and `barfoo`?

Comment: @sawa Very good point!!

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 
i didn't even think about that. if the match value has same string length, return both values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do:

```
ary = ['John', 'Johnson', 'Mike', 'Tim', 'Timberland']
ary.select {|e| ary.grep(Regexp.new(e)).size == 1 }
# => ["Johnson", "Mike", "Timberland"]
```

Comment: nice use of ary.grep -- i'd forgotten about that method

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following, in case when part is resided at the beginning of a word only:

```
array = ['John', 'Johnson', 'Mike', 'Tim', 'Brakatim', 'Weltimwel']
# => ["John", "Johnson", "Mike", "Tim", "Brakatim", "Weltimwel"]

array.reject {| v | " #{array.join( ' ' )} " =~ /\W#{v}\w/i }
# => ["Johnson", "Mike", "Tim", "Brakatim", "Weltimwel"]
```

Or in case when part is resided at the beginning of a word, and at the end or middle of it:

```
array = ['John', 'Johnson', 'Mike', 'Tim', 'Timberland', 'Brakatim', 'Weltimwel']
# => ["John", "Johnson", "Mike", "Tim", "Timberland", "Brakatim", "Weltimwel"]

array.reject {| v | " #{array.join( ' ' )} " =~ /\W#{v}\w|\w#{v}\W|\w#{v}\w/i }
# => ["Johnson", "Mike", "Timberland", "Brakatim", "Weltimwel"]
```